# How do I test interactions with private fields of a class with unit testing on java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mocking

**I have the following class**:

```
public class BookProcessor {

    private Map<String, Double> bookToValueRecord = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, Integer> bookToCountRecord = new HashMap<>();
    private int counter = 0;

    public void processBook(Book book) {
        counter++;
        recordBook(book);
        if (counter % 5 == 0) {
            printSomeReport();
        } if (counter % 10 == 0) {
            printAnotherReport();
        }
    }

    private void printAnotherReport() {
       //just print something
    }


    private void printSomeReport() {
        //print something else here
    }

    private void recordBook(Book book) {
        bookToValueRecord.put(book.getTitle(), book.getValue());
        bookToCountRecord.put(book.getTitle(), bookToCountRecord.getOrDefault(book.getProduct(), 0)+book.getCount());
    }
}
```

My idea was to create a Test class `BookProcessorTest` with field `BookProcessor testee;` I dont know if I need to mock it or not? One of my tests will be `shouldProcessBook()`. In this test I will create a sample `Book` object, then I will call `testee.processBook(myBookObject)`, but then what should I assert or verify? Should I check if this record has been saved into `bookToValueRecord`? If yes, how, given that this is a *private field*?
Also, how to test that after saving 5 books into my `Map`, I am printing some report? Should I test that `printSomeReport()` has been called? If yes, how, given that `printSomeReport` is *private method*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About how to test your class :

1) You need mocking as the class under test has some dependencies that you need to isolate.
But you don't have any dependencies to mock there.

2) `private` methods should not be tested and you should not either check that these was invoked during the test.
These are implementation details of the API : the public method `processBook()`.

3) An API that doesn't return anything but create a side effect can be tested only by having a way to notice the side effect.  You don't seem having that.

So what ?
In fact you are stuck because a) your class does too much things and b) your class stores things but doesn't provide a way to retrieve these things.

a) The `private` methods `printAnotherReport()` and  `printSomeReport()` should in fact be moved into `public` methods of dependencies that are actually missing.  For example introducing a `PrintService` class would be helpful.
In this way you could mock it and you could so check that these methods are invoked as expected.  For example update the class as :

```
private PrintService printService; // dependency 

BookProcessor (PrintService printService){
   this.printService = printService;
}
```

b) about the `recordBook() private` method, if `BookProcessor` composes some Books (`BookProcessor` is probably not a convenient name here because of that), `BookProcessor` should also provide way to retrieve them.
So adding a `public` method to retrieve added information seems required.
But note that you are not constrained to break the encapsulation of the `Map`s, you could provide methods that retrieve values from the key passed as parameter :

```
public Double getValue(String key){
    return bookToValueRecord.get(key); 
}

public Integer getCount(String key){
    return bookToCountRecord.get(key); 
}
```